# What's the preferred way to instantiate one class in another?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, design-patterns

Pretty basic question. Has to do with design preference but I think there are some caveats that I'm missing.

I want to have an instance of some class inside another class. The way I see it, I have 3 options:

1. Have the object `class2` inside `class1` as I have it below. This means it gets constructed when an instance of `class1` gets constructed. My issue here is that it may need a default and/or copy constructor? When I instantiate a `class1` object below, does it construct `class2_inst(args)` using that constructor? Or is `class2_inst` already created with some default constructor and the line `class2_inst(args)` simply *copies* an anonymous `class2` object?

   ```cpp
   class class2 {
     public class2(args) {
       ...
     }
   }

   class class1 {
     protected class2 class2_inst;
     public class1(args) : class2_inst(args) {
       ...
     }
   }
   ```
2. I can have a pointer to `class2`:

   ```cpp
   class class2 {
     public class2(args) {
       ...
     }
   }

   class class1 {
      protected class2* class2_inst;
      public class1(args) {
       class2_inst = new class2(args);
       ...
      }
   }
   ```

   This has the advantage that class2 isn't instantiated until I explicitly call the new operator.
3. Then there's using a reference instead of a pointer:

   ```cpp
   class class2 {
     public class2(args) {
       ...
     }
   }

   class class1 {
     protected class2& class2_inst;
     public class1(args) {
       class2_inst = new class2(args);
       ...
     }
   }
   ```

I want `class2_inst`'s life-time to match that of `class1`. No funny business with having `class2_inst` living outside of `class1`. So references may be the way to go.

Of the 3 methods, which is everyone's preferred way, and why?

Comment: There's no preference really, it all depends on your specific use case.

Comment: `public class1(args)` isn't valid C++

Comment: @user253751 obviously, the code shown is just pseudo-code, not meant to be compiled as-is.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Those snippets don't make sense either way...

Comment: You're right, I'll correct that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your examples are a bit backwards.  I think you meant this instead:

```cpp
class class2 {
  public:
    class2(args) {
      ...
    }
};

class class1 {
  protected:
    class2 class2_inst;

  public:
    class1(args) : class2_inst(args) {
      ...
    }
};
```

```cpp
class class2 {
  public:
    class2(args) {
      ...
    }
};

class class1 {
  protected:
    class2* class2_inst;

  public:
    class1(args) {
      class2_inst = new class2(args);
      ...
    }
};
```

```cpp
class class2 {
  public:
    class2(args) {
      ...
    }
};

class class1 {
  protected:
    class2& class2_inst;

  public:
    class1(args) {
      class2_inst = new class2(args);
      ...
    }
};
```

Now, that being said:

- Example 1 will work nicely for what you want, and is the preferred way to go: "*I want `class2_inst`'s life-time to match that of `class1`. No funny business with having `class2_inst` living outside of `class1`.*"  And to answer your question - yes, `class2_inst(args)` will construct the `class2_inst` member directly, not default-construct it and then copy an anonymous `class2` object into it.  See [Constructors and member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).
- Example 2 will also work, but to make it work *correctly*, you need to add a destructor to `class1` to `delete` the new'ed `class2` object, and you need to also add copy/move constructors and copy/move assignment operators to `class1` to copy/move `class2` objects properly, per the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

  ```cpp
  class class2 {
    public:
      class2(args) {
        ...
      }
  };

  class class1 {
    protected:
      class2* class2_inst;

    public:
      class1(args) {
        class2_inst = new class2(args);
        ...
      }

      class1(const class1 &src) {
        class2_inst = new class2(*(src.class2_inst));
        ...
      }

      class1(class1 &&src) {
        class2_inst = src.class2_inst;
        src.class2_inst = nullptr;
        ...
      }

      ~class1(args) {
        delete class2_inst;
      }

      class1& operator=(const class1 &rhs) {
        if (this != &rhs) {
          class1 tmp(rhs);
          std::swap(class2_inst, tmp.class2_inst);
        }
        return *this;
      }

      class1& operator=(class1 &&rhs) {
        class1 tmp(std::move(rhs));
        std::swap(class2_inst, tmp.class2_inst);
        return *this;
      }
  };
  ```

  You get all of that functionality for free in Example 1, as the compiler will auto-generate those extra methods for you.  Yes, there are valid cases where it makes more sense to use pointers for members, but this example is not one of them.
- Example 3 is simply not valid. You can't assign an object pointer to an object reference.   And why would you think "*references may be the way to go*"?  They are not, in this case.

So, in a nutshell, you should prefer *value sematics* whenever possible, but use *pointer/reference semantics* when needed.